# Conditional import in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, objective-c++

My app is in swift and has some files from other modules in objective-c. App has 2 targets, lets say Target-1 and Target-2. When I build the app, a file called as "Target(number)-Swift.h" is generated in build folder.

I need to import this file into the objective-c class. Since there are 2 targets and the file name depends on target name, I need to do conditional import based on which target I am running. I want something like:

```
if running Target1
   #import "Target1-Swift.h"
endIf

if running Target2
   #import "Target2-Swift.h"
endIf
```

If I directly add #import "Target1-Swift.h" it works fine when I build Target1, but fails when I build Target2. I tried the following:

**Code I tried:**

```
#ifdef TARGET1_SWIFT_H

#import "Target1-Swift.h"

#endif
```

With this I don't see errors on imports, but the I see errors like "Use of undeclared identifier 'class_name'" for the classes declared in "-Swift.h", so looks like "-Swift.h" file it not being imported.

Any idea how can I fix this.

Comment: What I've done in similar situations is to keep the file name the same but put the headers in target-specific folders.  That way I could change the search path for each target in settings to get the version I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Preprocessor macros** for this.

Assign a flag for only one target. And use that flag for a condition to determine which target you're running on.

[image]

You can use it in the swift file as follow.

[image]